# Mobilefirst PushNotification: On using wl_anonymousUserRealm at server, app is not calling onReceive method on clicking notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on IBM Mobilefirst native android app. I have written code to enable push notification. I am getting notification but I have an issue here.

On Launch of the app I am calling following code.

```
final WLClient client = WLClient.getInstance();
            push = client.getPush();
       ResponseListener listener = new ResponseListener(ResponseListener.AUTHENTICITY_CONNECT);    
        client.getPush().setOnReadyToSubscribeListener(listener); 
        challengeHandler = new AndroidChallengeHandler(realm);   
        client.registerChallengeHandler(challengeHandler);       
        WLRequestOptions options=new WLRequestOptions();
        options.setAppUserId("sample");
        client.connect(listener,options);
```

When I launch the app for the first time all the above code gets executed and the listener  calls the below method

```
 @Override
        public void onReadyToSubscribe() {
            WLClient.getInstance().getPush().registerEventSourceCallback(pushAliasName, "PushAdapter","PushEventSource", this);
        }
```

After this listener is getting executed i am calling subscribe method. I get success for the subscription to push.

On the server side I call the procedure to send the push notification and it reaches the phone.

Now when my app goes to background and I get a notification . I click on the notification and app restarts and never call onRecieve method of the registered interface.

**On click of the notification it relaunches the app and call the onReadyToSubscribe() again and it never calls the onRecieve method. what should I do to get the onReceive() method to be called and app shouldn't get relaunched(if app is already in background) on click of notification?**

My server side security test is as below

```
<customSecurityTest name="AuthSecurityTest">
        <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
         <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm" step="2" isInternalDeviceID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
```

The useridentity is not binded to security test but i am putting it in the apps applicationdescriptor. So it never call for credentials required of challenge handler on connect.

**Here I think this could be the issue in the sample code that is provided by MFP in 7.1 version security test has useridentity realm but in my case I am not using the custom useridentity realm but I am using the default wl_anonymousUserRealm. This is the issue because when i tried working with the sample code it works completely fine with all the scenarios. But with the wl_anonymousUserRealm I have this issue.**

Comment: The app is KILLED or CLOSED? If you kill the app, it quits the push service, if you close the app the service remains listening. How exactly are you closing the app?

Comment: I may click button in my app which may close the app or I go to the back stack of my phone and clear the app which may kill the app. In both cases I am getting the push notification. But my onRecieve method is not calledon click of notification..

Comment: On click of notification app is getting restarted. how do i stop it.

Comment: Here I think this could be the issue in the sample code that is provided by MFP in 7.1 version security test has useridentity realm but in my case I am not using the custom useridentity realm but I am using the default wl_anonymousUserRealm. This is the issue because when i tried working with the sample code it works completely fine with all the scenarios. But with the wl_anonymousUserRealm I have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vivin for the suggestions.
Here was the issue in the sample code that is provided by MFP in 7.1 version security test has useridentity realm but in my case I am not using the custom useridentity realm but I am using the default wl_anonymousUserRealm.

The actual issue was  wl_anonymousUserRealm generates a new random userid everytime. So when ever my app is relaunched my userid gets changed and I wont get push in onrecieve because it thinks a different user is logged into the app..

Now because I cant change the wl_anonymousUserRealm I am sending push using deviceid. Please check the below link(Adapter code as below).
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html#sendMessage

check sample client code from below link.
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-native-android-applications/tag-based-notifications-in-native-android-applications/

Answer (score 2):

onReadyToSubscribe() method getting called everytime the application connects to the server ( even if already subscribed for push) is expected and by design.

onReadyToSubscribe() is a call back that fires at the client denoting the token exchange between client and server is complete. This is required because tokens issued to an application by mediator can change. This makes it imperative that the server always stays updated with the latest token. If not , push notification will fail with invalid token error.

When the client connects to the server , they compare tokens - client presents the token it has now and server presents what it had stored. Three cases happen:

1) In a new registration , server does not have a token. Here client passes on what it got from the mediator, server persists it and issues a success. Client fires the onReadyToSubscribe() callback to indicate push handshake is complete and client can now subscribe to aliases or tags.

2) Client has received a new token from the mediator. This does not match the one server already has. Client passes on the new token to server, server updates its records with the new token and lets the client know. onReadyToSubscribe() call back fires at client indicating successful handshake. Earlier subscriptions records stay.

3)If the tokens match, then onReadyToSubscribe() fires denoting that push handshake is complete (no changes required)

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. This is fine, But there two things happening 1)If i click on notification my app gets restarted even if my app is open in the backstack 2) On click of notification onrecieve message is not called . Am i Missing something.

Comment: Vivin did you get some time to look into this issue. If you have some solution please share.

Comment: @Bender, If the application is in the background, it should only bring it to foreground and enter the onReceive callback. 2) onReceive should be called. 
I will verify this. What is the exact MFP version you are trying on?

Comment: Vivin I am using 7.1 version. I am assuming it could be a issue in my cod e to... I have posted a different question with the problem can you please look into this question and help me with a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867784/ibm-mobilefirst-how-to-recieve-push-notification-on-any-activity-of-app

Comment: Vivin : 
Here I think this could be the issue in the sample code that is provided by MFP in 7.1 version security test has useridentity realm but in my case I am not using the custom useridentity realm but I am using the default wl_anonymousUserRealm. This is the issue because when i tried working with the sample code it works completely fine with all the scenarios. But with the wl_anonymousUserRealm I have this issue.

Comment: Anonymous Realm creates a new identity every time. So, if you had already subscribed , the next time it connects to server, the identities ( the new one and one in server) do not match. In this case onReadyToSubscribe() will fire ( expected and explained earlier). However isSubscribed() will return false. Also , when you subscribed the earlier identity is updated with the new one - since there only be one user subscription from the app on the same device.

Comment: I defined a custom useridentity which is not binded to security test but i have defined it in my apps application descriptor . Can I bind this useridentity to the push anyway. <userIdentityRealms>customuseridentityrealm</userIdentityRealms>

Comment: This tag is used in the OAuth flow authentication flow. The first authenticated realm becomes the user authentication realm. If you are not particular about security, you can try Tag Based notifications which are not tightly coupled with security. You can use useridentity realms but these are not tightly coupled like Event source based notifications. Also, starting MFP 80, event source notifications are not supported and available.

Comment: Ok Vivin, I got your point thanks for helping me all the way. So i am planning to use the following link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html#sendMessage which talks about sending push using deviceid directly does this need and userid subscription.. I am assuming it shouldn't require any subscription. what do u say on this...

Comment: @Bender, you are right . Unicast notifications targeted by deviceid does not require a user subscription. You can try out this sample:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-native-android-applications/tag-based-notifications-in-native-android-applications/